# Display animated gif on jPanel

Tags: java

In the overridden function for my `JFrame`:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    BufferedImage imagePerson;
    try {
        imagePerson = ImageIO.read(new File("errol.gif"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        imagePerson = null;
    }

    g.drawImage(imagePerson, i * increment, j * increment - 1, null);
}
```

How can I change this so the animation on the gif is shown (without using threading). I have spent many hours trying to get this to work but to no avail.

Comment: Regardless of which solution you pursue, you probably don't want to actually be *loading* images each time `paintComponent` is called.  That method is a called a **lot**.  Load them once at initialization and store them in an instance variable of your class.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an `ImageIcon` for this purpose. Have a look [here](http://www.java-forums.org/java-2d/653-animation-animated-gif.html) and [here](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/use-animated-gif-image-in-jfc-swing-application). If you need the animation on a `JPanel`, simply add a `JLabel` (with the `ImageIcon`) to the panel.

Comment: The thing is I want to move the position of the animated gif around the jpanel with positions worked out in :protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

Comment: and I can't see a way of adding a jlabel to the jpanel in that function

Comment: Either you move your ImageIcon around, or you set up a Timer that calls repaint repeatedly, and figure out where and which frame to draw in your paintComponent method.

Comment: Add the label to the panel. Then to move the label you simply invoke setLocation(). There is no need to override the paintComponent() method or call repaint().

Answer (score 1):

Check this example for displaying an animated gif in Swing. you dont have to use any threads:

```
Icon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("ajax-loader.gif"));
JLabel label = new JLabel(imgIcon);
label.setBounds(668, 43, 46, 14); // for example, you can use your own values
frame.getContentPane().add(label);
```

[Source](https://tutoref.com/how-to-display-an-animated-gif-in-java-swing/)