# Animated GIF in Java?

Tags: java, image, netbeans, applet, animated-gif

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Display animated gif on jPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339029/display-animated-gif-on-jpanel)
>   [Show animated gif in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935232/show-animated-gif-in-java)

So I am creating a game applet in Java, using Netbeans. It is textbased, but I want to display an animated GIF image on the front page. I only know how to display static images. Could anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Show animated gif in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935232/show-animated-gif-in-java) and [Display animated gif on JPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339029/display-animated-gif-on-jpanel)

Answer (score 1):

You might try putting the animated GIF into a JLabel.  If I remember correctly, the JLabel will automatically animate the GIF.