# How to create rotating circle animation in java?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, paint

I want to create a rotating circle in the middle of `JPanel` and be able to set start/stop rotating and also set to visible/invisible.

**Does any body know how to do it or any existing example?**

```
private static class RotatingCirclePanel extends JPanel {        
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    }                      
}
```

**This is an example of it.**

[image]

**Edited:** This is first version.Can any body help to make it as in gif example?

```
public class ProgressWheelPanel extends JPanel {
private double angleInDegrees = 1;
private Timer rotatingTimer;

public ProgressWheelPanel() {
    rotatingTimer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
        //            @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            angleInDegrees = angleInDegrees +1;
            if (angleInDegrees == 360) {
                angleInDegrees = 0;
            }
            repaint();
        }
    });
    rotatingTimer.setRepeats(false);
    rotatingTimer.start();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    rotatingTimer.stop();

    g2d.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g2d.setBackground(Color.white);
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.3f));
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER));
    g2d.rotate(angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180.0, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    g2d.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, getWidth() / 2 + 100, getHeight() / 2);
    //**************************************************************************************
    AffineTransform transformer = new AffineTransform();
    transformer.translate(5,5);
    transformer.scale(2,2);
    g2d.getTransform().concatenate(transformer);
    //***************************************************************************************
    g2d.dispose();
    rotatingTimer.start();
}
public void start(){
    rotatingTimer.start();
}
public void stop(){
  rotatingTimer.stop();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ProgressWheelPanel demo = new ProgressWheelPanel();
    WebButton btnStrat= new WebButton("Start"),btnStop= new WebButton("Stop");
    btnStrat.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            demo.setVisible(true);
            demo.start();
        }
    });
    btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            demo.stop();
            demo.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
    cp.add(demo,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    cp.add(btnStrat,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    cp.add(btnStop,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setLocation(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Jeez, hope noone with a propensity for epileptic seizures visits this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339029/display-animated-gif-on-jpanel

Comment: possible duplicate of [JTabbedPane: show task progress in a tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055336/jtabbedpane-show-task-progress-in-a-tab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055336/jtabbedpane-show-task-progress-in-a-tab/10055387#10055387) contains a code snippet to create such an icon based on an image. It basically uses code to rotate an icon, and a `Timer` which triggers the rotation to get the animated effect.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply display an animated GIF on either a [JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935232/show-animated-gif-in-java) or a [JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339029/display-animated-gif-on-jpanel)*, using for example the image displayed in your question, and then set the visible/invisible properties of the control containing the image. However, this doesn't give you a way (that I know of) to start/stop the animation at any given point in time.

If you want full functionality including start/stop, you'll probably have to roll your own. In that case, start coding! We'll gladly help you when you get run into problems, but we won't write the code for you. (But before you start working on this, ask yourself: do you really need, I mean *really* need, the start/stop functionality? If you can make do with show/hide, you're already home...)

---

*) There are many [other resources](http://www.java-forums.org/java-2d/653-animation-animated-gif.html) on [animated gifs](http://www.java-forums.org/java-2d/653-animation-animated-gif.html) that might come in handy.

Comment: Animated GIFs can chew up memory resources & should send with caution

Comment: My code is updated, I made the first version. It can rotate/start/stop but it is not yet as in animated gif in example above. I don't know yet how to make gray background circle.